# No functionality in mongoose Model.deleteOne()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to use the mongoose Model.deleteOne() method to delete an object within a collection. However, Model.deleteOne() provides no result at all.

**Code:**

```js
const id = interaction.options.get('id')?.value as string

ModerationData.deleteOne({
    _id: id,
    guild_id: interaction.guild?.id
})
```

Comment: what do you mean by `result` ? do you mean it does not work or it does not give a `response` ?

Comment: @unhackit It doesn't work.

Comment: need to await `await ModerationData.deleteOne(`.

Comment: @turivishal Thanks! For some reason, this made it work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by awaiting Model.deleteOne(). Thanks to @turivishal for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using _id to find the required document and then trying to delete it. You can use `findByIdAndDelete()` method as well for the same functionality. Here is a code snippet for the same -

```
ModerationData.findByIdAndDelete(id, function (err, docs) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } else {
    res.redirect("/home");
  }
});
```

Here `id` is a variable holding the `ObjectID` value for the document.

Comment: I saw this method but unfortunately its not exactly what I'm looking for. I'm trying to delete a document by ID, but I'm also using other properties (guild_id).

Comment: How about using find query first and then using delete query?

Answer (score 0):

Try `findOneAndRemove`

```js
const id = interaction.options.get('id')?.value as string

ModerationData.findOneAndRemove({
    _id: id,
    guild_id: interaction.guild?.id
})
```